# NodeJS json provided in request is not sent with push

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am trying to call my api for a post webservice from a Node application.
I successfully pulled data from this same api with a get method, so connexion works perfectly.
Now I want to make a push

```
    request({
        method: 'POST',
        url: ws.url,
        json: {"id": 78, "product" : "MyProduct"}
    }, function (error, response,body) {
        console.log('error ',error);
        console.log('body ',body);
        console.log('response ',response);
        cb(error, response)
        //console.log(error, response)
    })
```

I ve got these console.log :

```
error  undefined
body  undefined
response  { errMsg: 'id not provided ' }
```

So the response is quite explicit, API havent received my id.
However when I call manually same ws with Postman, it works normally.

So what s wrong with my json param? should I send it another way?
My webservice needs to have this content in its body and nothing else:

```
{"id": 78, "product" : "MyProduct"}
```

Comment: have you tried using `JSON.stringify({id: 78, product : "MyProduct"})` ?

Comment: @yvoytovych yes i tried, normally Request is supposed to stringify my json itself but I tried to provide a stringified json and also a body node with stringified value instead of json

Comment: maybe try to include `contentType: "application/json"` to your post request

Comment: @yvoytovych — "json - sets body to JSON representation of value and adds Content-type: application/json header. Additionally, parses the response body as JSON." — https://github.com/request/request

Comment: @NicolasD Make sure your API handles "application/json" formatted body (not application/x-www-form-urlencoded) Also check if it takes id from request body not from url.

Comment: try compare what is sent during your post request in app, and in postman

Comment: I think there might be some issue with the Web service. Track the code in webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue, and in fact the project where I am working extended Request library, and issue is in the method that overrode Request original behaviour.
So to sum up, my code above is supposed to work, I just have to fix this dirty override.